# Show all tags but exclude a certain tag

Tags: tags, exclude

I'm trying to get it work with tag__not_in but it doesn't work.

```
$args = array('order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'count', 'number' => '70',  'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'tag__not_in'=>array('28,24'),'hide_empty' => FALSE, 'title_li'=> __( '' ), 'show_count'=> 1, 'echo' => 0 );
```

any idea how I could work this out?

Comment: Your array is incorrect. Try `'tag__not_in'=>array(28, 24)`. And check the PHP docs for creating arrays

Comment: twas still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__not_in' => array( 37, 47 ) ) );
```

tag_not_in id is not string, so you don't need to quote the numbers. For Deep in Query check in [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Tag_Parameters)